# smart way to keep track of staking info

Tags: algorithm, stake

I have a contract for staking NFTs, called "Stake".
where someone will send a token and claim some rewards over time. I need to keep track of what/who sends.

something like this

```
struct StakeInfo {
    address createdBy;  //INPUT
    uint256 tokenID; // INPUT
    address nftContract; // INPUT
    ...other stuff
}

mapping(uint256 => StakeInfo) public stakes;
```

I need to generate a unique key for the above mapping that's created from an **address**, a **uint256** and another **address**

the other solution is to have a simple counter, and keep track who owns that counter, but I'm wondering is there a more smart way to keep track of such things...

Answer (score 0):

a potential solution is this:

```
bytes32 stakeKey = keccak256(abi.encode(_tokenId, _nftContract, etc, etc....));
lastClaim[stakeKey] = block.timestamp;
```